# Asynchronously iterate through an array and then return the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am trying to iterate through an array asynchronously and then want to push the values from a called function to a new array.

I have the following code but not sure how to approach this...

```
let companies = [];
_.forEach(notProcessed, function(company) {
    companies.push(processThem(company));
});
return companies;
```

Of course when printing / returning companies, I will receive an empty array.

Thanks ahead time, any help is appreciated!

Comment: If `processThem()` has asynchronous code in it need to create promise array but would need `processThem()` to return a promise also in order to push it's promise into the array. Then use `Promise.all()` on the array of promises

Comment: Show sample code for `processThem()`

Comment: `I will receive an empty array` - no, you should be getting an array that is as long as `notProcessed` array, it's just the values in the array are likely to be all `undefined`, or whatever `processThem` returns

Comment: Assuming `processThem()` has asynchronous code in it, we need to see that actual function to provide the best help for you because that's the first place you need to do something different.  Please show us that code so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it:

```
var notProcessed = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function processThem(company) {
  // Example long process
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(company), 500);
  });
}

function processArrayAsync(notProcessed) {
  var companies = [];
  var promise = Promise.resolve();
  for(let next of notProcessed) {
    promise = promise
      .then(() => processThem(next))
      .then(company => companies.push(company));
  }

  return promise.then(() => companies);
}

processArrayAsync(notProcessed).then(console.log);
```

And there is a better way using new in es6 `async` functions

```
var notProcessed = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

async function processThem(company) {
  // Example long process
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(company), 500);
  });
}

async function processArrayAsync(notProcessed) {
  var companies = [];
  for(let next of notProcessed) {
    let res = await processThem(next);
    companies.push(res);
  }
  return companies;
}

processArrayAsync(notProcessed).then(console.log);
```

I really like this second way of handling async operations :)